# Replace a smaller image with a larger one (after the larger image loads)

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a few images of superheroes. These are in divs along with much larger images of astronomical objects. These larger images take a while to load. I want the astronomical images to replace the superhero images after they've loaded.

Here's what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/vmpfc1/5typ7pnp/1/

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <div class="pix"style="background: url('http://baltimorepostexaminer.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/spider-man2_pole_4681.jpg'); height:200px;width:200px;">
    </div>
    <div class="true-image" style="background: url('http://m1.i.pbase.com/o9/27/876727/1/151851961.JlvdQ9xW.GreatCarinaKeyholeandRedHoodNebulae3454x2566pixelsimproved3.jpg')"></div>
    </div>

  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <div class="pix"style="background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/75/Comic_Art_-_Batman_by_Jim_Lee_%282002%29.png'); height:200px;width:200px;">
    </div>
    <div class="true-image" style="background:url(' https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/706439main_20121113_m6triptych_0.jpg')"></div>
  </div>

</body>
```

js:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('.true-image').attr('style').on('load', function () {
        $('.pix')({
            'background-image': 'url(' + $(this).attr('src') + ')'
        });
    });
}, 0);
```

css:

```
.true-image {
    display : none;
}
```

I am a javascript newbie -- is there a decent way to make the larger space images replace the superhero placeholders?

Is there an easier way to do this in HTML5?

Comment: lazy load - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/lazy-loading-images/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited Answer to reflect changes:

```
<div style="background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/sOcRl3M.jpg'); height:400px;width:400px" rel="https://i.imgur.com/xr7CRQo.jpg">
</div>

<div style="background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/1m0NwgN.png'); height:400px;width:400px" rel="https://i.imgur.com/nlFPkc4.jpg">
</div>
```

Then you can have jQuery to loop through all images which has a `rel` attribute. 2 or 2,000 images, it does not matter.

```
$('div[rel]').each(function() {
  var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
  var self = $(this);
  var img = new Image();
  $(img).load(rel, '', function() {
    self.css('background-image', 'url('+rel+')');
  });
});
```

You can see it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/83zLumuk/4/

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Because of reasons, I need the structure to be divs with background images like the HTML in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vmpfc1/83zLumuk/2/

Do you know how to get the js to work in this case?